# Can I use Axios with ReactJS in a static page?

Tags: forms, reactjs, post, request, axios

I want to create a contact form for my react app, which is a static app (I have no back-end at all, only front-end). I'm trying to do this with a POST request to a certain API, and I found that [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) may be helpful. I want to do something like when the user clicks the Submit button, it calls a function that does all the validations on the form, and then submit the data via a POST action with Axios.

Is this possible, or am I wrong with my approach? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. What you'll want to do is listen for the `onSubmit` event of your form and send the POST request in that listener. You can do the validation inside that method as well.

```js
handleSubmit(e) {
  // Stop browser from submitting the form.
  e.preventDefault();

  // Validate here or directly when setting state.
  // ...

  // Then send a POST request to your endpoint.
  axios
    .post('https://your-form.com/endpoint', {
      // Your data goes here.
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      // Done!
      console.log(response);
    })
}

// In the render method: listen for the submit event.
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
```

Here's a working example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    // Stop browser from submitting the form.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Validate here or directly when setting state.
    // Then send a POST request to your endpoint.
    axios
      .post('https://reqres.in/api/users', {
        firstName: this.state.firstName,
        lastName: this.state.lastName
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          value={this.state.firstName}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          value={this.state.lastName}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.2/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```